# How i can get value $scope.TobaccoProduct_0 , $scope.TobaccoProduct_1

Tags: javascript

How i can get value of TobaccoProduct_0 , TobaccoProduct_1, TobaccoProduct_2.

Currently i am trying with this code and its not working

```
for (var count = 0; count < $scope.ProductCount; count++) {

    if ($scope.TobaccoProduct_[count] == true) {
        $("#SmokeReview").submit();
    } else {
        alert("plz chcek atleast one value");

    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array. Move on.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var count = 0 ; count < $scope.ProductCount; count++) {

    if ($scope["TobaccoProduct_"+count] == true) {
         $("#SmokeReview").submit();
    }
    else {
         alert("plz chcek atleast one value");
    }
}
```

You really shouldn't be doing it this way though. You should surely be using some kind of array to store the Tobacco products rather than numbering the variable name.

**Edit:** You might actually be doing it that way (otherwise you'd have a really strange ProductCount implementation) and so the above solution won't work, you'll have to use `$scope.TobaccoProduct[count]`